# Type/Interface used with request body validation is ignored

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, loopback

Given the following interface defined inside a controller:

```
interface idAndAge {
 id : string,
 age : number
}
```

and here is the endpoint definition:

```
@put('/tests')
  async replaceById(
    @requestBody() test: idAndAge,// <--to validate the input
  ): Promise<void> {
    await this.testRepository.updateAll(test,{id : test.id});
  }
```

When this endpoint receives the following input for example (which has properties not defined in the interface):

```
{ anyKey: anyValue }
```

it accept it and ignore the validation

it should not allow the below values - because they are not included/against our interface idAndAge

```
{ anyKey: anyValue }
```

please check [this repo](https://github.com/frodoe7/LB4RequestbodyValidation) , if you'd like to test the issue

Comment: There is no validation at run time. Only at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Decorators_openapi.html) you need to add the corresponding model decorators to your model:

> In order to use @requestBody in a parameter type, the model in the parameter type must be decorated with @model and @property.

So you could simply do:

```
@model()
class idAndAge {
  @property({ required: true })
  id: string;
  @property({ required: true })
  age: number
}
```

and loopback will correctly validate the request body against the generated json-schema.

Update:
Afaik there's currently no support to add a "allowAdditionalProperties" decorator, but you could directly use the json-schema in your requestBody-decorator as follows:

```
@requestBody({
      required: true,
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: {
            type: 'object',
            additionalProperties: false, // <=== important
            properties: {
              id: { type: 'string' },
              age: { type: 'number' }
            },
            required: [
              "id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }})
```

Comment: the model is already exist , but I need a customized validation in the requestBody

Comment: Sorry, but have you actually tried my solution? You'll get an 422 validation error if you send the payload `{ anyKey: anyValue }` which is exactly what you want, right?

Comment: yes but this will force me to enter the whole model , in my case - I need it to allow me send {id : string} or {age : number} - I don't want to enter all of them

Comment: still ,`test: idAndAge` force the whole model

Comment: No, this definitely allows you to send payloads of just `{age : number}` and `{id : string}`, since these properties are not set as required in the schema. What error do you get?

Comment: Thanks @eol , that was really helpful! - I have another question inside the same case : how to make one of the properties required ? for example {age : 23} as an input - it will accept it . I'd like to make the id property required

Comment: @AhmedMohsen: No problem, I've updated my answer. Just add the `required`-property in the schema.

Comment: thanks so much - I have extra tiny question , here `properties: {
              id: { type: 'string' }
             names: {type: 'array'}
            }` - `type: 'array'` not works - how to put array type ?